How to print all key-value pairs of certain sections in an INI file?
The INI file is Firefox's profiles.ini.
I want to print everything under [Profilen] including the section headers, where the n's are non-negative integers, with a blank line separating each section.
There is also an optional Default key under [Install*] that is different from the Default keys under the profiles sections, and I want to print that too if present.
Basically the shell script was just grep -E 'Default=[^1]' profiles.ini and grep -A4 '^\[Profile' profiles.ini before (to print the Name, IsRelative, Path and an optional Default keys and values), but this'll fail if keys are added or deleted, and the -A option of grep is not portable.
Here is my hacky solution, which is neither idiomatic nor robust AWK:
/^[[]Profile[0123456789]{1,}[]]$/ {
    print
    while ((getline) > 0) {
        if ($0 ~ /^$/) { # Should really break on new sections.
            print ""
            break
        } else {
            print
        }
    }
}
/^Default=/ {
    print # Default profile path given in the Install* section.
}

Example input:
[Profile2]
Name=default-test
IsRelative=0
Path=/home/user/ffprofiles/f9bwn86n.default-test

[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=x64qf7nv.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2

[Install22379532B4E49482]
Default=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696
Locked=1

Example output:
[Profile2]
Name=default-test
IsRelative=0
Path=/home/user/ffprofiles/f9bwn86n.default-test

[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=x64qf7nv.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696

Default=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696

How can I do this more concisely and correctly?
The solution doesn't actually have to be in AWK, but I think awk is more suitable in this case than sed or any other Unix utilities.
The solution, however, must be portable and POSIX-compliant.
Thank you in advance.

Better add a real sample input/expected output

And for me it's not clear enough is you want other sections below the searched one or only the relevant section

Also, getline is rarely the right approach (it's not in this case) but if you're ever considering using it in future please read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first to understand the many caveats/gotchas and when/how to use it.

@EdMorton I see Stack Exchange is being strict as usual, but I've updated my question to include what you've requested. I'm enumerating the digits so that locale doesn't have any effect on it. Are [[]/\[ and {1,}/+ exactly equivalent in theory and in practice? Which one is more portable? And thanks for the link, I've bookmarked and glanced through that article just days before.

They're equivalent, + is more portable than {1,} as the former works in all awks while the latter only works in "modern" awks (so it won't work in old versions of gawk, for example). [[] and \[ can be different depending on the context they're used - the former always means "a literal [" while the latter means that only if not in a context where it gets interpreted twice, e.g. a dynamic regexp in awk.

I would say, though, that if your awk variant doesn't support {1,} then it's time to get a new version of awk as that one is very outdated and then who know what other common functionality it might be missing.

Using any awk:
$ awk '
    /^\[/ { sect = substr($0,2) }
    (sect ~ /^Profile/) || ( (sect ~ /^Install/) && /^Default=/ )
' profiles.ini
[Profile2]
Name=default-test
IsRelative=0
Path=/home/user/ffprofiles/f9bwn86n.default-test

[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=x64qf7nv.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696

Default=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696


awk is capable of keeping state between lines without the need for getline(). If you require an awk-based solution, the easiest method would be:
cat profiles.ini | awk '
    /^\[/                 {ok=0}
    /^\[Install\]$/       {ok=1; header=$0}
    ok && /^Default=/     {print header; print}
'
cat profiles.ini | awk '
    /^\[/                 {ok=0}
    /^\[Profile[0-9]*\]$/ {ok=1}
    ok                    {print}
'

As a single awk script, this might work:
/^\[/                 {ok=0}
/^\[Profile[0-9]*\]$/ {ok=1}
/^\[Install\]$/       {ok=2; header=$0}
ok==1                 {print}
ok==2 && /^Default=/  {print header; print}

Always saving the header and doing a string comparison might make it clearer, but might also have the opposite result. (I have not tested this version at all.)
/^\[/                 {hdr=""}
/^\[Profile[0-9]*\]$/ {hdr=$0}
/^\[Install\]$/       {hdr=$0}
hdr ~ /\[Profile/               {print}
hdr ~ /\[Install/ && /Default=/ {print hdr; print}


Useless use of cat: awk ... profiles.ini

It's deliberate. The pipeline goes left-to-right.

Left to right, without cat: <profiles.ini awk ....

Yes, but this is Unix.SE, not CodeGolf.SE. Even Kernighan and Pike in their "The Unix Programmer's Environment" in 1980s admit that cat|... is often found more natural. I would have used awk '{script}' foo.ini or awk -f script foo.ini if it were a single line as that would be the more readable version in that case; in this case the more readable version is the one with 'cat'. (Which is all dwarfed by the two separate 'awk' invocations anyway, but those also were kept separate for clarity even if it's technically possible to merge them into one script.)

Neither cat file | awk '...' nor < file awk '...' give you access to the input file name in FILENAME, nor do they work easily when there's multiple input files whose content needs to be handled separately (both very common situations) so, since you need awk '...' file(s) in many cases, just use that syntax in all cases for consistency and to avoid unnecessary rework later if/when you discover you need that syntax and so you simply don't even have to think about which syntax to use in any given situation.

\] is undefined behavior per POSIX so YMMV regarding what that'll do in any given awk since ] is only a regexp metachar if it follows an unescaped [, which isn't the case in your script. Just get rid of the \ and make it ] alone to be portable to all awks.

@EdMorton Or just [[] and []] so I don't have to remember the rules of when to escape the brackets?

Yup, that'd work too. The same is true of ) btw - \) is undefined behavior so the meaning of /\(foo\)/ or /[(]foo\)/ is undefined but /\(foo)/, or /\(foo[)]/ or /[(]foo[)]/ is defined to mean the ( and ) are literal.

What you're describing is the a structured text file format with context.
awk might (will) be able to extract the specific section, but it'd need to make a lot of assumptions that aren't based in how the file format actually works, but how the specific example you think of happened to look like (starting from "easy" to address things like "does capitalization matter" to more interesting things as "how do I deal with two sections with the same name, and overlapping keys?").
So, simply don't use awk, sed or any other mostly context free parser approach to parse something like ini files. Use a parser with knowledge of the format.
The format here is TOML, by the way.
You use posix, which indicates that you can use a C99 compiler (that's a tool as POSIX as awk!). So, instead of an awk-based TOML parser, go for an established and well-working TOML library. toml-c is a library that you can just drop as header file next to your .c file. The examples/ directory has two examples that you can directly adapt to your use case; just replace toml_parse(char*,…) with toml_parse_file(FILE*,…), and open the file you got passed as argv[1]; easy.
Not gonna deliver a full C99 solution just because you think that POSIX utilities is the way to portability – it frankly sadly isn't; different implementations of the same POSIX utility are typically more incompatible across platforms than say Python interpreters, and every platform for which you get an awk preinstalled very likely also has a python.
Speaking of Python, that comes with a toml parser included, here's your 9-line script, including usage help, to print all key/values from a given section. Since it will error out with a non-zero return value when you give it a section name that doesn't exist in your input, a simple shell loop can be used to handle Profile0, Profile1… until ProfileN+1 doesn't exist anymore. More elegant would be to actually do this in Python itself, but that's left to the reader as example, since that would be very specific, whereas this tool is more generally useful:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tomllib
from sys import argv, stdin, stderr, exit

if len(argv != 2):
  stderr.print(f"USAGE: {argv[0]} SECTION-NAME < inputfile.ini\n")
  stderr.print(f"Prints all key/value pairs from a section in a INI\n")
  stderr.print(f"(or generally, TOML) file, separated by a sheep.\n")
  exit(127)

ini = tomllib.load(stdin)
section = ini[argv[1]]
for key, value in section.items():
  print(f"{key}  {value}")


tomllib is only included in the standard library since Python 3.11, and I'm wary of using Python because of the Python 2/3 divide and naming mess (python, python2, python3). It also might not be as ubiquitous as awk (is it available in most BusyBox installations?) and I don't want to ask users to install anything, so it should be a utility that is preinstalled on most Linux and BSDs, macOS, and Solaris 11. I'm content with an approximate solution that doesn't understand the whole INI format.

I assure you that I've met more systems without awk than python, but that's anecdotal evidence only. I don't think something as "most" BusyBox installations is something one can define; most busybox systems are deeply embedded computers (fridges, routers, car dashboards) or smart phones, so I don't know whether it's worth thinking about what they might need, unless you are specifically targetting a specific device with busybox built in a way that enables the awk applet.

re: Python version: the Py2/3 thing is done, it works as python3 everywhere I tried. If you need only "oldskool ini files" (from your original description I was assuming you didn't, not all classical ini parsers deal with space characters in sections, and you used one), then import configparser is your friend

How is it possible that you have met more systems without awk than Python? Awk is several decades older and tens of megabytes smaller than Python with as many if not more implementations. Is it one of those avant-garde operating systems like Manjaro Linux that makes questionable choices such as not including vi/vim by default?

I won't count on python3 the name being always available without manually symlinking or installing some stub packages, and Python has very bad backward compatibility, so configparser or tomllib I use today might be removed later. I want stability.

The format in OP's example is definitely not TOML. It is vaguely similar to TOML, in that TOML was inspired by it, but it does not follow the TOML syntax and indeed tomllib raises a syntax error at the 2nd line (due to string values not being quoted, something that INI and TOML formats have the opposite rule on). Python's ConfigParser would be a more likely module.

@Gao A software being old is no guarantee for it being used everywhere. Ada is a lot older than Java, but how many smart phone apps do you think are written in Ada? So, that's not really an argument. Same for ed vs Visual Studio Code, ksh vs bash or zsh, and so on.

"Python has very bad backward compatibility, so configparser or tomllib I use today might be removed later. I want stability" Um, yeah, that is counterfactual. configparser has been around for 20 years. Whatever you do, it's not going to be as stable as core libraries in Python3, promise. You're aspiring highly, and that's honorable, but thinking your config file parser needs to outlive Python longetivity borders on hybris, maybe :) But anyways: don't ignore that pretty "standard" tools like make, sed etc do break occasionally, too. Either you pin your software versions, or you need to

have some contingency plan for when something minor needs to be adapted to a newer version of the awk  implementation a target system runs. Frankly, a well-readable awk script is easy to maintain in the future, so not that bad a choice! But: if the alternative is 9 lines of Python that actually parses an ini file, instead of doing a fragile approximation of it, then that's the better choice, as in the end, you want robustness not long-lived, fragile software: it's IMHO more likely that some unforeseen variation of the input data breaks your "would-be" parser than that a real parser

becomes unavailable.

@grawity note that this is the output, not the input of the awk script, in Gao's question. But you're right, if that's the quoting in the input file that we see in the output, we have a problem with tomllib, but not with configparser. A simple substitution in the script above, though!

@MarcusMüller Python 3.13 removed 19 modules from the standard library (some of the removed modules, e.g. telnetlib, has been around since at least Python 2.0, released in 2000). Also, I recall Python has a release policy of only giving deprecation notice 2 minor releases beforehand and could be removed after that. Compare that to Java, where the only real change is Java 9+, and only some people are affected by it.

At least with POSIX we have some vague rules to point at which when violated we can blame the implementations for introducing "bugs", and also because currently my script does not have a dependency on Python (well, not even awk except this part). I'm not ruling out Python as an option yet, but I'm going to see what other solutions are available.

what that is worth in practice, where tools then violate POSIX? IMHO, not that much, but your opinion seems to differ on that, and we shouldn't be arguing about opinions! My main point was that "long-term stable" is less valuable than "can definitely deal with all input that you'll present it with, and easy to fix in the future".

@Gao I see you mentioned Solaris in a comment. Just be aware that the default awk on Solaris in /usr/bin is old, broken awk (see http://awk.freeshell.org/oawk) so don't use that version - use one of the other awk versions that come with Solaris, i.e. nawk and, preferably, /usr/xpg[46]/bin/awk.

@EdMorton Didn't Solaris 11 get a big overhaul? That was true for Solaris 10 and older, which I am not supporting. Is it still the same in Solaris 11?

I haven't had access to a Solaris machine for years so I can't test it but I haven't heard of any change to the default awk and I'd be surprised if they changed it since doing so would cause a lot of existing scripts that rely on old awks "functionality" to break. If you do have access to a Solaris 11 machine you could try running some of the scripts from http://awk.freeshell.org/oawk and then let us know if /usr/bin/awk is still old awk or not.

@EdMorton You are correct, it is the old awk (and the old grep without support for the -E option) in /usr/bin! I'm honestly quite surprised since /usr/bin/sh in Solaris 11 is ksh93, but they haven't upgraded the other utilities. I guess I have to alter the PATH at the beginning of my script.

As long as you are happy to extract one key-block at a time you can get away with a single awk command. End of each block is conveniently another [key], or the end of file.
Here is the command to extract, say, [Profile0]:
$ awk '/^\[Profile0/{p=1; print; next} /^\[/{p=0}; p>0{print}' ini.txt 
[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696

or extract the block that starts with [General]:
$ awk '/^\[Gen/{p=1; print; next} /^\[/{p=0}; p>0{print}' ini.txt 
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2

I have used [Gen and [Profile0 in these examples. Replace them with enough characters from your intended [key] that uniquely identify the block.
The file ini.txt is your input, i.e.:
$ cat ini.txt 
[Profile2]
Name=default-test
IsRelative=0
Path=/home/user/ffprofiles/f9bwn86n.default-test

[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=x64qf7nv.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2

[Install22379532B4E49482]
Default=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696
Locked=1


awk '/^\[/{p=(/^\[Profile0/)} p' ini.txt would be the more concise, idiomatic way to write that than awk '/^\[Profile0/{p=1; print; next} /^\[/{p=0}; p>0{print}' ini.txt to do what that script does but the OP also wants to print Default=9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696 from just the Install block so a different approach may be more useful.

Using awk:
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"} 
  /^\[Profile/; 
  /^\[Install/ && match($0,/\nDefault=[^[:space:]]+/){
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
   }' file


The following two commands are portable to any Unix system that can run Andrey Kislyuk's tomlq wrapper around the ubiquitous jq JSON parser, which I believe is a broader set of systems than what can run Firefox.
My only assumption is that any string after a = is already an adequately encoded TOML string, sans double quotes.
First, the input may be converted to the standard TOML format by quoting all values:
sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/' input

We may then extract the Profile sections:
sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/' input |
tomlq -t 'with_entries(select(.key | startswith("Profile")))'

Given the example in the question, this should give us
[Profile2]
Name = "default-test"
IsRelative = "0"
Path = "/home/user/ffprofiles/f9bwn86n.default-test"

[Profile1]
Name = "default"
IsRelative = "1"
Path = "x64qf7nv.default"
Default = "1"

[Profile0]
Name = "default-release"
IsRelative = "1"
Path = "9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696"

If you don't like the spaces around the equal signs or the added quotes, then remove these by passing the output through sed 's/ = "\(.*\)"/=\1/'.
We can then separately get the Install section's Default value, if it exists:
sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/' input |
tomlq -r 'with_entries(select((.key | startswith("Install")) and (.value | has("Default"))))[].Default'

... or, if you're okay with getting an empty line for non-existing data, just
sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/' input |
tomlq -r 'with_entries(select((.key | startswith("Install"))))[].Default'

Given your example input, this should give you the plain value
9hv1fbkk.default-release-3426201712696

(We can't combine the two commands as TOML can't represent non-objects at top-level.)

Using this approach, you can easily extract, e.g., the section that has the Path value that corresponds to the Install section's Default value (Profile0 in the example):
sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/' input |
tomlq -t 'with_entries(select(.key | startswith("Install")))[].Default as $default | map_values(select(.Path == $default))'


@EdMorton I agree that I was bending the language. I will modify that part of my text.
